# Uninstall Firefox

Tags: 14.04, firefox, google-chrome, uninstall

Just installed on my new laptop Ubuntu 14.04 and **immediately** installed Chrome (for programming purposes).
I havn't done anything with Mozilla Firefox yet and I want to remove it since I have Chrome.
How do I remove Firefox?

Another qustions were asking how to remove Firefox after long use..
I'm sure I don't need to write all the command lines their answers suggested..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Open a terminal and type `sudo apt-get purge firefox`, you can wipe remaining traces by following the answers to the question linked below.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Software Center lets you install, reinstall, and remove applications, including Firefox.  I use the manual way above myself, but there are those that that might prefer this way.  The key is the small search box in the upper left corner of the Window.  Type in the name of the app (firefox) or group (browser), and a list of choices should come up.  The manual command line method works, but you have to know the application package name.  Or use partial names with wildcards, but that can be chancy.